# ToString method for char array

Tags: c#

I read a String from the Console and put it in the array called 'array'
then I output the 'array' to the Console and it is fine, then I apply the ToString method to the 'array' and put it in a String called 'jj', then I out put the 'jj' and I get this :
System.Char[]

I have a good reason why I am doing this, It is just that I sis not show you the whole program.

I do not understand why.
Please help me.

```
 String uno = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] array = uno.ToCharArray();
 Console.WriteLine(array);
        String jj = array.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(jj);
```

Answer (score 5):

The first example (`char[] array`) will print fine because `Console.WriteLine` accepts an overload of char array -- see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-6.0#system-console-writeline(system-char())).

The second example (`string jj`) does not work because `ToString` is not overriden in `System.Array`, which is what your character array derives from, so `Object.ToString` will be called instead, as all types derive from `System.Object`. This is why `System.Char[]` is printed -- the type of this object.

You can construct a new string from the char array like so:

```
string jj = new string(array);
Console.WriteLine(jj);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a constructor for `string` that accepts a `char[]`. You should therefore try this:

```
var jj = new string(array);
Console.WriteLine(jj);
```